# How to get the exact coordinate of a view in android?

Tags: android, layout, view

i want to create an app where the users can link two text Views by an arrow;
for example when a user click in a the left Text view and in the right Text view the app should generate automatically  a line, the problem that i have is to locate the exact coordination of the two views i tried using get Top() ... but always the position of the arrow   wasn't in the right place the same result using getLocationOnScreen();

```
...

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();


        float dw = d.getWidth();
        float dh = d.getHeight();

        bit = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        can = new Canvas(bit);
        paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bit);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            can.drawLine(text.getLeft() + text.getWidth(), text.getTop() + (text.getHeight()/2), button.getLeft(), button.getTop() + (button.getWidth()/2), paint);

            iv.invalidate();
                }
        }
        )
        ;



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried textView.getX(); for x co-ordinate and textview.getY() for y co ordinate...